# Get value of input element with same ID via jQuery created in ASP.Net

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, foreach

I have `foreach` in ASP.Net:

```html
@foreach (var item in journalOfRepair)
{   
  <td>
   <div class="PriceWork"> <input class="form-control" type="text" value="@item.Price" style="width: 75px;"></div>
  </td>
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
$('#PriceWork').children('input').each(function () {
    alert(this.value); // "this" is the current element in the loop
});
```

I need to get each value of input with `id="PriceWork"`. I also need to get the sum of values with `id="PriceWork"`. It must be unique but I do not know how to realize it. Then I want to add an `onblur` event handler and pass the sum to another function.

**Jquery code works but incorrectly. It alerts one time instead of many.**

some part solved but

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

function CalculateWorkHand() {
            var sum = 0;

```
        $('#PriceWork').each(function () {
            sum += parseFloat($(this).value());  // Or this.innerHTML, this.innerText
        });
        alert(sum)

    }
```

Sum outputs 0. Why?

Comment: The issue is moot as you cannot have the same `id` on multiple elements within the DOM. Use classes instead. If you'd like more specific help, please add your current JS to the question so we can help you debug it

Comment: OK, do I need use class for input or contain it in <div>? and how get element value in that case?

Comment: I have added code in jquery

Comment: `#` is ID, `.`  is class. Your code will work if you do `$('.mxm input').each` - but I would put the class on the input or the table cell and not have a div

Comment: but I use class for form-control

Comment: You can have more than one class `<input class="mxm form-control" `

Comment: or `<td class="PriceWork"> <input class="form-control" ` using `$(".PriceWork input").each`

Comment: I simplify question. I need to add another and add realize it by steps